# Python 3, urllib ... Reset Connection Possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

In the larger scale of my program the goal of the below code is to filter out all dynamic html in a web-page source code

code snippet:

```
try:
    deepreq3 = urllib.request.Request(deepurl3)
    deepreq3.add_header("User-Agent","etc......")
    deepdata3 = urllib.request.urlopen(deepurl3).read().decode("utf8", 'ignore')
```

The following code is looped 3 times in order to identify whether the target web-page is Dynamic (source code is changed at intervals) or not.

If the page IS dynamic, the above code loops another 15 times and attempts to filter out the dynamic content.

QUESTION:

While this filtering method works 80% of the time, some pages will reload ALL 15 times and STILL contain dynamic code. HOWEVER. If I manually close down the Python Shell and re-execute my program, the dynamic html that my 'refresh-page method' could not shake off is no longer there ... it's been replaced with new dynamic html that my 'refresh-page method' cannot shake off.  So I need to know, what is going on here? How is re-running my program causing the dynamic content of a page to change. AND, is there any way, any 'reset connection' command I can use to recreate this ... without manually restarting my app.

Thanks for your response.

**UPDATE:**

I've made a minu executable html grabber which I run in a loop from the main script. It solves this problem but I'm still curious as to why I needed to do this.

Comment: Looks suspiciously like a caching issue. Consider adding `.add_header('cache-control': 'no-cache')`.

Comment: Thanks 9000. I was hopeful your method would work, but it doesn't.

.add_header('cache-control': 'no-cache') - results in an error
.add_header('cache-control:', 'no-cache') - no error, but doesn't resolve my issue.

Thanks for having a crack at it. Any other takers?

Comment: Debug what is going on: `print connection.headers` and any other bit of information to see what changes when you restart the shell. If you could give an example URL and exact code, I'd check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the connection after reading the data:

```
try:
    deepreq3 = urllib.request.Request(deepurl3)
    deepreq3.add_header("User-Agent","etc......")
    connection = urllib.request.urlopen(deepurl3)
    deepdata3 = connection.read().decode("utf8", "ignore")
    connection.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Nightcracker .... I've tried this one before. To no avail. The strangest thing is that I can repeat the process countless times while one Shell is open and the result will be the same every time i.e the same caught dynamic code will be filtered out ... the same non-caught dynamic code will remain. But the moment I restart the Shell, the old non-caught dynamic code is GONE replaced with new non-caught dynamic code that never goes away until I restart the shell yet again. I'm starting to think this is server-side caching ... but that still doesn't explain how the restar

Answer (score 0):

I've made a minu executable html grabber which I run in a loop from the main script . and use it to solve this problem but I'm still curious as to why I needed to do this.